# Spacy MemoryError

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I managed to install spacy but when trying to use nlp then I am getting a MemoryError for some weird reason.

The code I wrote is as follows:

```
import spacy
import re
from nltk.corpus import gutenberg

def clean_text(astring):
    #replace newlines with space
    newstring=re.sub("\n"," ",astring)
    #remove title and chapter headings
    newstring=re.sub("\[[^\]]*\]"," ",newstring)
    newstring=re.sub("VOLUME \S+"," ",newstring)
    newstring=re.sub("CHAPTER \S+"," ",newstring)
    newstring=re.sub("\s\s+"," ",newstring)
    return newstring.lstrip().rstrip()

nlp=spacy.load('en')
alice=clean_text(gutenberg.raw('carroll-alice.txt'))
nlp_alice=list(nlp(alice).sents)
```

The error I am getting is as follows

[The error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kyGNV.png)

Although when my code is something like this then it works:

```
import spacy

nlp=spacy.load('en')
alice=nlp("hello Hello")
```

If anybody could point out what I am doing wrong I would be very grateful

Comment: Hmmmm...can you look at your computers memory usage and check if it is being entirely used? Task manager in windows or activity monitor in mac.

Comment: Probably because `list(nlp(alice).sents)` uses all your memory...

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you truly are running out of memory. I couldn't find an exact number, but I'm sure Carrol's Alice's Adventures in Wonderland has tens of thousands of sentences. This equates to tens of thousands of `Span` elements from Spacy. Without modification, `nlp()` determines everything from POS to dependencies for the string passed to it. Moreover, the `sents` property returns an iterator which should be taken advantage of, as opposed to immediately expanding in a list.

Basically, you're attempting a computation which very likely might be running into a memory constraint. How much memory does your machine support? In the comments Joe suggested watching your machine's memory usage, I second this. My recommendations: check if your are actually running out of memory, or limit the functionality of `nlp()`, or consider doing your work with the iterator functionality:

```
for sentence in nlp(alice).sents:
    pass
```